# Email-To-Case feature in Salesforce

Tags: case, email2case

This is a simple step in Salesforce - Setting Up Email to case: I set up my own official address for Email-To-Case.

But the case is not getting created in Salesforce whenever I shoot an email with the email addresss provided.

Comment: Email address provided means? Is that long sandbox specific address or your official email id?

Answer (score 1):

For setting up email to case following are the requirements:

1. Email to case in Salesforce require email to be added and an E2C record xreatedy. Once record is created, you get a routing address which is a long email type address.
2. For the email you added the E2C record. Go to your email inbox. Go to settings >  you have to setup  forwarding by adding the routing ( long email type) address generated from email to case.
3. Once you add the routing an email will be sent with a verification link/ code. This email sent from your email  inbox would have created a case in salesforce where you will have to verify it.
4. Once verifed any email which will be sent to the E2C email record will start creating cases in salesforce.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have missed the verification step, during the setup process. Step #5 in this article: [Configure Routing Addresses for Email-to-Case and On-Demand Email-to-Case.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customizesupport_configuring_routing_addresses.htm&type=5)

Comment: Thank you for all your help! It's working now!!